# z-index for select options

Tags: html, css

I want to set select menu option z-index. By default it is set on top.

Step to produce bug: click on select menu and hover a tag.

[image]

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('a').hover(function() {
            $('div').show()
            })
        })
    </script>


    <style>
        select option { position : relative; z-index : 5 }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style = "position:absolute; display  none; background : #F00; width : 200px; height : 200px; z-index : 100000">new</div>

    <select>
        <option>jitender</option>
        <option>chand</option>
        <option>alok</option>
        <option>srisvasta</option>
    </select>

    <a href = "#">hover</a>
</body>
```

Comment: You should crop the canvas seriously... Edit: I said crop that, and you removed it :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing the select popup behind another element is not possible, you can however blur the select element with `$('select').blur()` to close the select after hovering.

Comment: It is working fine in all browser except chrome. any guess why it is not working for chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
$(function(){
 $('a').hover(function(){
 $('select').hide();
 $('div').show()
})})
```